# String Encryption in Linux

Tags: linux, encryption, cryptography

Could any please tell me how I can take in a 16 character string and generate a 16 character encrypted string ( In human readable format ) using command line tools.

I have explored options like openssl but I am not able to control the length of the output.

Could anyone please advise?

Comment: How strong does it have to be? If you don't require military-grade encryption, then a simple substitution cipher (modified by a secret key) will probably work and would be simple to implement yourself.

Comment: Thanks Jim, but is there any command line tool I can use to get this done. It does not have to be very strong encryption.

Comment: Use the super-awesome ROT26 tool called "cat".

Comment: Flagged for being off topic: not a programming question - I am wondering if this is possible using command line tools. Firstly you will have to specify the character encoding and range to see if it is answerable at all...

Comment: You may well find that ROT13 is built in somewhere.  For something stronger use Vigenère.

Answer (score 3):

There is a description of ROT13 in Linux [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1792/rot13-using-the-tr-command).  I have not tested it:

`$alias rot13="tr '[A-Za-z]' '[N-ZA-Mn-za-m]'"`

That may meet your needs, though it is not at all secure.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "abcdefghijklmnop" | gpg --armor -c --output -
```

However, this will not break down into your 16 character limit.

Resulting output:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.10 (GNU/Linux)

jA0EAwMCnM6hI0xpVVFgyScCfr6Zo2fZeuiVWteZKeptcvSBj9wxk2gRMqTERtz9
8dNUHZq2eRA=
=Jpku
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Comment: Thinking about it, I do not believe there is any true 'encryption' that is guaranteed to give you the exact number of characters as output that you gave it as input.  There's some obfuscation techniques to be sure (like the above mentioned rot13), but no true encryption.

Comment: With a one-time pad of the same size, you can always generate a `strong` encryption (not `true` encryption - rot13 is absolutely true, but not at all strong).

Comment: Yes, but the one-time pad would need a password as long as the text, _and_ the password would have to be randomly generated (uniform distribution for each character).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where this will be used an what are the details of your security requirements, so I'll answer based on the information you gave. You require:

- strong encryption;
- output must be the same size of the input;
- output must be human-readable.

If you give up any one of those requirements, it's easy. If not, it's hard -- if not impossible with standard Linux/Unix tools.The standard block ciphers will encode data in blocks, so they do have the same size for input and output -- but they transform bit sequences into bit sequences, and there is no guarantee that the output will be "readable". You can then encode the output in HEX (base16) or base64, but that will expand it (that's what UtahJarhead meant by "will not break doen into your N character limit").

Possible solutions (each breaking one requirement) are:

- Use weak encryption (a substitution cipher like ROT13 -- or, if you want something a bit more sophisticated, implement the [Vigenère cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher), but you'd have to code it -- or trust someone else's implementation);
- encrypt using AES or some other good block cipher (via OpenSSL, as you mentioned), then run base64 on the output;
- encrypt using AES or some other good block cipher (via OpenSSL), but don't expect anyone to read the output.

One last point: an encryption scheme is something hard to devise and to implement and there are too many subtleties involved, so creating an ad-hoc encryption method is not recommended at all...

***edit***: as mentioned in a comment to another answer, you could implement a one-time-pad, but you'd need paswords as long as the text, and each character of the password would need to be chosen with uniform distribution over the alphabet. Hashing the password, encoding as ascii and taking the first n characters is *probably* good enough [1].

Anyway, remeber that is the plaintext is too short *and* it can be "tested" (like passwords to sites or to encrypted documents), the adversary can do an exhaustive search.

[1] Some cryptologists will not agree that you can consider the output of a hash function as "random" (you'd be using the "Random Oracle model"). The encoding of the hash must be such that, given a uniform distribution of bits in the input, there is a uniform distribution of letters as output. When you combine this "pad" with the message, it must be a one-to-one mapping, so the distribution of the final output is uniform.

Comment: If you implement Vigenere you could just as well implement some rotor machine, like enigma too. That will also give the same output size. There are enigma implementations available, but they are not installed as default.

Comment: Yes, good point! Enigma is good also -- but not the same thing as a good modern block cipher...